# Google Places API Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-places-api, rails-activestorage

I am trying to use the Google Places API to help me create a Resturant Object for my Resturant Model on my Ruby on Rails project. Given an exact address, I want it to populate the field of my Resturant object and create a new Resturant. When I input an address, the response will say that there are no candidates and one of the fields is incorrect (e.g. Google Places API Response: {"candidates"=>[], "error_message"=>"Error while parsing 'fields' parameter: Unsupported field name 'website'. ", "status"=>"INVALID_REQUEST"}". Here is my current code.

```
  def create_with_places_api
    @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)
  
    # Fetch additional details from Google Places API
    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json"
    query_params = {
      input: @restaurant.address,
      inputtype: 'textquery',
      fields: 'name,nationalPhoneNumber,website,formattedAddress,types,priceLevel,photos',
      key: 'MY_KEY-IM_NOT_TELLING_YOU'
    }
  
    uri = URI(url)
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(query_params)
    Rails.logger.info "Google Places API Request URL: #{uri}"
    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    google_place_data = JSON.parse(response.body)

    Rails.logger.info "Google Places API Response: #{google_place_data}"
  
    if google_place_data['status'] != 'OK' || google_place_data['candidates'].empty?
      # If the API request fails, return a JSON response with an error message
      Rails.logger.error "Could not find the restaurant details from Google Places API. Response status: #{google_place_data['status']}"
      render json: { success: false, message: "Could not find the restaurant details from Google Places API. Please check the address and try again." }
      return
    end
  
    # Populate the restaurant attributes with the fetched data
    google_place = google_place_data['candidates'].first
    @restaurant.name = google_place['name']
    @restaurant.phone = google_place['nationalPhoneNumber']
    @restaurant.website = google_place['website']
    @restaurant.address = google_place['formattedAddress']
    @restaurant.cuisine = google_place['types'].join(', ')
    @restaurant.price_range = google_place['priceLevel']
  
    # Fetch photos of the place from the Google Places API
    if google_place['photos'].present?
      photo_references = google_place['photos'].first(8).map { |photo| photo['photo_reference'] }
      photo_urls = photo_references.map { |reference| "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=#{reference}&key=MY_KEY-IM_NOT_TELLING_YOU" }
      @restaurant.images.attach(io: URI.open(photo_urls[0]), filename: 'photo_1.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpg') if photo_urls[0].present?
      @restaurant.images.attach(io: URI.open(photo_urls[1]), filename: 'photo_2.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpg') if photo_urls[1].present?
      @restaurant.images.attach(io: URI.open(photo_urls[2]), filename: 'photo_3.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpg') if photo_urls[2].present?
      @restaurant.images.attach(io: URI.open(photo_urls[3]), filename: 'photo_4.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpg') if photo_urls[3].present?
      @restaurant.images.attach(io: URI.open(photo_urls[4]), filename: 'photo_5.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpg') if photo_urls[4].present?
      @restaurant.images.attach(io: URI.open(photo_urls[5]), filename: 'photo_6.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpg') if photo_urls[5].present?
      @restaurant.images.attach(io: URI.open(photo_urls[6]), filename: 'photo_7.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpg') if photo_urls[6].present?
      @restaurant.images.attach(io: URI.open(photo_urls[7]), filename: 'photo_8.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpg') if photo_urls[7].present?
    end
  
    if @restaurant.save
      # If the restaurant is successfully saved, return a JSON response with the restaurant ID
      render json: { success: true, restaurant_id: @restaurant.id }
    else
      # If there are validation errors, return a JSON response with the errors
      Rails.logger.error "Restaurant validation errors: #{restaurant.errors.full_messages}"
      render json: { success: false, errors: @restaurant.errors.full_messages }
    end
  end
```

I'm really new to all this and learning as I go. So Im sure I am doing something stupid. I would be grateful if you could look over the whole code because I am sure once I get the fields correct, I'm going to have some other issues. I am also using active storage to store images of the restaurant. Please let me know if I left out any details,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Places API returns "Unsupported field name 'address\_component'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731369/google-places-api-returns-unsupported-field-name-address-component)

Comment: @RubyRacer that's just plain wrong https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place#optional-parameters

Comment: I'd recommend that you use Find Place to only fetch the `place_id` then use that `place_id` to fetch your specified fields using Place Details. I'm not familiar with Ruby. So I'll just leave here a somewhat similar question but only on python. You both had the same `INVALID_REQUEST` error after using fields with Find Place: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76781958/im-trying-to-find-some-hotel-public-phone-numbers-in-google-using-python-and-go/76810096#76810096

Comment: Make sure though that you are not storing the Places Data since from what I know, that would be agains their [ToS 3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#:~:text=3.2.3%C2%A0Restrictions%20Against%20Misusing%20the%20Services.)